# How to implement like showing videos one by one in page view and showing progress for all videos at bottom of the pageview with pause and resume?

Tags: flutter

I have stored the videos address in a list and used Future delayed() function to increment index after some duration(Duration of gif). It also failed. And also I don't know how to implement linear progress bar for each gif at bottom of the container with space separated. I can implement single linear progress bar for some duration. But I want the bar for the count of videos playing with play one after another.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the implementation with [gif_view](https://pub.dev/packages/gif_view) pacakge and make use of the **onFinish** function to switch the gif each time.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. I have completed this issue by converting the gif into the short videos.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the gifs into videos. And I used Video Player Controller to control the each video like pausing and resuming videos. This code works like the pageview builder will show videos based on the input from calling widget. This will choose videos from  map (gifNames) and shows one by one when we swipe each page. The progress bar also show progress of each video. We can pause and resume videos. You can implement like moving each pages automatically.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';
import 'package:quiver/iterables.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gif_view/gif_view.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/linear_percent_indicator.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class AppBarGifImage extends StatefulWidget {
  //const AppBarGifImage(String category, {Key? key,required this.category}) : super(key: key);
  final String category;

  AppBarGifImage(this.category);

  @override
  _AppBarGifImageState createState() => _AppBarGifImageState();
}

class _AppBarGifImageState extends State<AppBarGifImage> {
  Map<String, List<String>> gifNames = {
    'Automobile': ['bikeservice.mp4', 'carservice.mp4'],
    'Beauty and fashion': ['menservice.mp4', 'womenservice.mp4'],
    'Electronics': [
      'laptopservice.mp4',
      'mobileservice.mp4',
      'tabletservice.mp4'
    ],
    'Home Services': ['housecleaning.mp4', 'housepainting.mp4']
  };
  int videoIndex = 0;
  int progressIndex = 0;
  PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  late VideoPlayerController _controller ;
  //late VlcPlayerController vlcPlayerController ;


  void updateDuration(int value){
    setState(() {
      videoIndex = value;
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/${gifNames[widget.category]![videoIndex]}')..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
    })..setLooping(false)..initialize().then((value) => _controller.play());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() async {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ShaderMask(
            shaderCallback: (rect) {
              return LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [Colors.white, Colors.transparent],
              ).createShader(
                  Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height));
            },
            blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 250,
              child: PageView.builder(
                controller: _pageController,
                itemBuilder:(cntx,index) {
                
                  return _controller.value.isInitialized ? GestureDetector(
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                          child: VideoPlayer(_controller)),
                      onTap: () {
                        if(_controller.value.isPlaying){
                          _controller.pause();
                        }
                        else if(_controller.value.position!= _controller.value.duration && !_controller.value.isPlaying){
                          _controller.play();
                        }
                      },
                    )
                      : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                },
                itemCount: gifNames[widget.category]!.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                onPageChanged: (pageNo){
                  setState(() {
                    progressIndex = pageNo;
                    videoIndex = pageNo;
                    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/videos/${gifNames[widget.category]![videoIndex]}')..addListener(() {
                      setState(() {});
                    })..setLooping(false)..initialize().then((value) => _controller.play());
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: range(gifNames[widget.category]!.length).toList().map((element) =>LinearPercentIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: element<progressIndex? Colors.white:Colors.grey,
                    linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.25,curve: Curves.linear,
                    //animation: true,
                    percent: element == progressIndex ? _controller.value.position.inMilliseconds/_controller.value.duration.inMilliseconds: 0,
                    //animationDuration: _controller.value.duration.inMilliseconds,
                    progressColor: Colors.white,
                  ) ).toList(),
                ),
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).